# Return List based on generic T

Tags: c#, generics

I want to convert list of `TEntity` to list of `TDto`.

```
    private List<TDto> ConvertUEntityToDto<TDto, TEntity>(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
    {
        if (entities is IEnumerable<Entity1>)
        {
            var result = new List<EntityDto1>
            foreach (var entity in entities)
            {
                result.Add(_mapper.Map<EntityDto1>(entity ));
            }

            return result;
        }

        else if (entities is IEnumerable<Entity2>)
        {
            var result = new List<EntityDto2>
            foreach (var entity in entities)
            {
                result.Add(_mapper.Map<EntityDto2>(entity));
            }

            return result;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

From code above i get an error:

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List< EntityDto>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List< TDto>'

How to return dynamically List of `T` from generic method in C#?

Comment: What is the relation between `EntityDto2` and `TDto`? You declare return type to be `TDto` but initialize a list of `EntityDto2`. Change list to be `List<TDto>`

Comment: `Tdto` is classm but where i write `where TDto : class`still the same error

Comment: Technically, `return result as List<TDto>` might solve your problem. But, as @GiladGreen has noted, there are better ways to achieve this generic mapping and it would usually include some usage of generic constraints to denote the relationships between the types involved.

Comment: What is the benefit of making this generic function, seems like you already have to have the logic in the mapper implementation? And Could do with just entities.Select(e => _mapper.Map<TDto>(e)); ?

Comment: The problem is that you're writing type-specific code in a generic method. You either need to make your code inside generic, by using `TDto` instead, or you will have to ask the compiler to trust you in that the types are compatible, by either doing `x as TDto` or `(TDto)(object)x`, depending on the types involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of generics are to use them! The if-else should precede your generic function (also see edit below).

```
if (entities is IEnumerable<Entity1>)
    ConvertUEntityToDto<TDto1, Entity1>(entities);
else if (entities is IEnumerable<Entity2>)
    ConvertUEntityToDto<TDto2, Entity2>(entities);
else ; //do nothing
```

and inside *ConvertUEntityToDto* it should use the T (TDto) as follows:

```
private List<TDto> ConvertUEntityToDto<TDto, TEntity>(IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
{
    var result = new List<TDto>
    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        result.Add(_mapper.Map<TDto>(entity));
    }
    return result;
}
```

The error was because the return type didn't match with the signature of your function.

### But I want to mention

You could just pass in a list, iterate it with `foreach` and if the element within the list is of type T, then Add to your new `List<T>` which you return.

Also, you should have [constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) for T.

### Edit:

What I mentioned above, to return all element of the list, only which matches the type TDto (and to get rid of the preceding if-else block), we can use the following snippet (by referencing `System.Linq` in the project) (thanks @Janne Matikainen to mention):

```
private List<TDto> ConvertUEntityToDto<TDto, TEntity, Tmixed>(IEnumerable<Tmixed> entities)
{
    return entities.Where(e => e is TEntity).Select(e => _mapper.Map<TDto>(e));
}
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
private List<TDto> ConvertUEntityToDto<TDto, TEntity, Tmixed>(IEnumerable<Tmixed> entities)
    => entities.Where(e => e is TEntity).Select(e => _mapper.Map<TDto>(e));
```

Comment: Nice, but u used in Convert method `Tdto2` without mention, could you explain relation between `Tdto2` and `Tdto`?

Comment: It was a copy paste issue of your code. See now. :) Would be easier if you would use T and U (or any letter).

Comment: Also you can just make the method as "return entities.Select(e => _mapper.Map<TDto>(e));" ie nullifying the point of the generic method to begin with. Basically making this as extension method would be most beneficial

Comment: @JanneMatikainen Extension method idea may not apply here! Since `_mapper` (global object) would turn to static (or at least a reference type parameter) which is very un-threadsafe! Also, `entities` is a reference type: that itself would make the function un-threadsafe! But thanks for the Linq idea. :)